# Could you explain me how environment variables work here?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, heroku, deployment

I have a project which I developed locally on my computer. Now I want to deploy it to Heroku.
For the local version I use SQLite and for Heroku version I'm going to use PostgreSQL.

I found a code, which easily lets me combine two databases depending on where I "reach" the program: locally or on Heroku.

```
if on_heroku:
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
else:
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://localhost:5432/myblog'
```

Looks interesting but I don't get the whole idea behind it. Could someone explain to me how it works or recommend me what to read?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, the os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] connects to the postgres db url of the postgres db add-on provided in your application. However, if your application does not have a heroku connection (assuming that is the conditional provided in `on_heroku`) then it accesses a local postgres db.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way of writing it is:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', 'postgres://localhost:5432/myblog')
```

because the other solution requires you to write logic to detect whether you are on Heroku `on_heroku`.

Basically if the environment variable `DATABASE_URL` exists, take the value of that. If not use the default value `postgres://localhost:5432/myblog`